# Dumping multiple variables to disk in Json. One variable per line

Tags: python, json

Say I want to dump multiple variables to disk with Json. They way I usually do this is by creating my variables as entries in a dictionary and then dumping the dictionary to disk:

```
with open(p_out, 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(my_dictionary, fp)
```

This creates a json file where the dictionary is saved in a long line:

```
{"variable_1": something, "variable_2" something_else, ...}
```

which I don't like. I would prefer to have my variables dumped into the text file with one variable per line, e.g something along these lines:

```
{variable_1: something\n
 variable_2: something\n
 variable_3: something_else}
```

Is there a way to do this with Json in Python?

Comment: Assuming you had the dict `{'variable_1': 'something'}`, would you want the output file to contain `"variable_1": "something"` or `variable_1: something`.  Without the quotes it is not JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `indent` option to `0` or more:

```
with open(p_out, 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(my_dictionary, fp, indent=0)
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump):

> If *indent* is a non-negative integer, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that indent level. An indent level of 0, or negative, will only insert newlines. `None` (the default) selects the most compact representation.

Your example would be output as:

```
{
"variable_2": "something_else", 
"variable_1": "something"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this inserts new lines within each object as well (e.g. if `variable_1` is a list, it will also insert new lines between every pair of items in the list). Is there a way to have new lines only between variables?

Comment: @user273158: no, there isn't. You'd have to use `.dumps()` to dump to a string, then post-process before writing the result out to your file.